# How to change root activity name in .NET HotChocolate for Elastic APM using a CustomActivityEnricher?

Tags: asp.net, graphql, hotchocolate, elastic-apm, observability

I am trying to change the root activity name in .NET HotChocolate for Elastic APM by creating a custom activity enricher and overriding the CreateRootActivityName method.

```
public class CustomActivityEnricher : ActivityEnricher
{
    public CustomActivityEnricher(ObjectPool<StringBuilder> stringBuilderPoolPool, InstrumentationOptions options): 
                            base(stringBuilderPoolPool, options)
    {

    }

    protected override string CreateRootActivityName(Activity activity, Activity root, string operationDisplayName)
    {
        return operationDisplayName;
    }
}
```

I added it as a Singleton service, as described in the documentation of HotChocolate and in this video demonstration:

[Instrumentation](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v12/server/instrumentation)

[GraphQL Observability with Elastic and OpenTelemetry - Michael Staib](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCLSfJMihsg)

`services.AddSingleton<ActivityEnricher, CustomActivityEnricher>();`

But this doesn't seem to work for me. Instead of getting the name of the query I am running, I get the endpoint of my GraphQL server.

[image]

Edit:
This is the configuration of my GraphQL server:

```
services.AddGraphQLServer(schema.Organization.GetGraphId())
                ...
                .AddInstrumentation(o =>
                {
                    o.RenameRootActivity = true;
                    o.IncludeDocument = true;
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this by assigning a new name to the APM transaction when diplayName contains '{'

```
protected override string CreateRootActivityName(Activity activity, Activity root, string displayName)
{
    var baseName = base.CreateRootActivityName(activity, root, displayName);
    
    var trans = Agent.Tracer.CurrentTransaction;
    
    if (displayName.Contains('{'))
    {
        trans.Name = displayName;
    }
    
    return baseName;
}
```

Comment: This seems to do the job for us too. Thank you <3